# What is the difference between passport-azure-ad vs passport-azure-ad-oauth2

Tags: node.js, adal, azure-active-directory, passport.js

We have application that is developed using MEAN stack. and we are planning to use Azure AD for authentication.

**Client Side**
In angular the client side resources are protected using [adal JS library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) based on article [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-angular/)

**Server Side Node Web API**
To protect server side web api i was following the article [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-nodejs/) which uses 
[passport-azure-ad](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad) node module. However on [passportjs](http://passportjs.org/docs) web site i came across one more node module [passport-azure-ad-oauth2](https://github.com/auth0/passport-azure-ad-oauth2)

So the question is what's the difference between [passport-azure-ad](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad) vs [passport-azure-ad-oauth2](https://github.com/auth0/passport-azure-ad-oauth2)

Comment: The article you reference is horribly incomplete. "Create a key and copy it somewhere, we will use it later.." and then they never do.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of `passport-azure-ad`. `Passport-azure-ad` comes from Microsoft and was built to support not just OAuth2 but also scenarios in preview such as [B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/) and [B2B](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2b-collaboration-overview/) and soon our [converged endpoint](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2015/09/04/working-with-the-converged-azure-ad-v2-app-model/) that we announced at BUILD 2016.

`passport-azure-ad-oauth2` is from [Auth0](https://auth0.com) team not affiliated with Microsoft, but they are perfectly good team with good documentation as well. I don't know their level of support for the other scenarios above.

*Azure Active Directory is an open platform and strives to use open standards like OAuth2 and Open ID Connect so that developers have this kind of choice.*

So, you are free to use whatever library you'd like, but of course from my perspective I'd advocate using the Microsoft OSS libraries on GitHub where they exist, like `passport-azure-ad`.

Does that help? Feel free to let me know if you run in to any problems with `passport-azure-ad` if you continue down that route.

Comment: Thanks!! That really helped

Comment: will it work with express? the article i was following is using restify

Comment: Yes. Restify borrows from Express and is used to expose APIs so I'd really recommend that if you are building a REST API using OAuth, but if you are looking for routes, etc. for login interactively try this sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-node-webapp-openidconnect

Comment: Thanks Again. One last question. Our application has Angular UI + Node Web APIs. We don't want unauthenticated user to directly call API. I am assuming "passport-azure-ad" WILL NOT protect any server side api. I was following this article i think written by you :) to protect server side API https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-nodejs/

Comment: Sure it will! You just invoke a passport plug-in on the URL you want to protect. You basically let it know what endpoints you want to protect and it will always either ask for a token or return an error. This is actually a feature of passport.js the library, not my plug in :-)

So instead of:
`server.get('/tasks/:owner', getTask);` - which will let anyone in

You add additional param (the passport plugin) to lock it down: 

`server.get('/tasks/:owner', passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', {
session: false
}), getTask);`